# Formula field cannot be grouped in SOQL GROUP BY query call

Tags: soql, formula-field, group-by

I have a `Pipeline__c` object with fields `Segment__c`, `Status__c`, and `Sales_Date__c` (among many other fields).

I also have a `Sub_Pipeline__c` object which is related to `Pipeline__c`. Inside I have the following fields:

- `Pipeline_Project_Name__r`: Master-detail relationship with `Pipeline__c`
- `Segment_f__c`: formula field `TEXT(Pipeline_Project_Name__r.Segment__c)` (I do this because I want the value of `Segment__c` in `Sub_Pipeline__c` to be read-only.)
- `Status_f__c`: formula field `TEXT(Pipeline_Project_Name__r.Status__c)` (similar reason as above)
- `Term_f__c`: formula field similar to above, that derives its value from `Sales_Date__c` in `Pipeline__c`

I would like to create a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT Segment_f__c, Status_f__c, Term__c, SUM(Profit__c)
FROM Sub_Pipeline__c WHERE Fiscal_Year__c = '2018'
GROUP BY Segment_f__c, Status_f__c, Term__c
```

However, when I tried running this I got the error message

```
Field 'Segment_f__c' can not be grouped in a query call
```

This error message is the same for the other two fields as well.

Does this mean I cannot use formula fields in GROUP BY clause? If so, what should I do to get to the end-result I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't group by formulas, but you can group the fields, if they are groupable:

```
SELECT Pipeline_Project_Name__r.Segment__c, Pipeline_Project_Name__r.Status__c, Pipeline_Project_Name__r.Sales_Date__c, SUM(Profit__c)
FROM Sub_Pipeline__c WHERE Fiscal_Year__c = '2018'
GROUP BY Pipeline_Project_Name__r.Segment__c, Pipeline_Project_Name__r.Status__c, Pipeline_Project_Name__r.Sales_Date__c
```

Comment: Ok this is awesome. I managed to get the first two fields to work, but for `Term__c` I cannot do it that way. For reference:

Comment: CASE(MONTH(Sales_Date__c), 
1,"1H / 1Q", 
2,"1H / 1Q", 
3,"1H / 1Q", 
4,"1H / 2Q", 
5,"1H / 2Q", 
6,"1H / 2Q", 
7,"2H / 3Q", 
8,"2H / 3Q", 
9,"2H / 3Q", 
10,"2H / 4Q", 
11,"2H / 4Q", 
"2H / 4Q")

Comment: @ohseekay Oh, I see. Yeah, you'd have to make a backing field (plain text) that could be populated by a workflow field update/process builder/trigger to set the correct value.

Comment: It derives its value based on the month of the sales date, and I want to be able to group by this term value in the table too.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What is a backing field? How do I do this?

Comment: Just a normal text field driven by a workflow rule. It would be updated each time the Sales Date changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring all the fields on Parent object `Pipeline__c` and only you are performing `SUM(Profit__c)` from Child object `Sub_Pipeline__c`, I would suggest you to create a Rollup Summary field on `Pipeline__c` object since relationship is Master-Detail.

And then you can perform the query on Parent object easily and might not to use `Group By` and simply use `ORDER BY` on those attributes.

Just check that how you can get Fiscal Year on Parent object.